# How to get a list of css attributes of an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, list

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easier way to preserve a list of CSS attributes I will change and then restore for any element in a JSON object using jquery without having to write a function such as getAttributes below.

Lets say I have an array of 3 attributes I would like to preserve for element :

I can write this as a function it would look like this:

```
  function getAttributes(elem, attrs){
    var obj={};
    $.each(attrs,function(i,attr){
        obj[attr]=$(elem).css(attr);
    });
    return obj;
  }

  oldAttrs=getAttributes('input',['color','background-color','font-size']);

  $('input').css({color:'green', 'background-color':'blue', fonts-size:'10px'});
  ......
```

Later I can then just do this elegant method to restore :

```
$('input').css(oldAttrs);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a jQuery function for this, but the static method `window.getComputedStyle` works for all modern browsers and IE9.

```
var cachedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(domElement);

// later
$(domElement).css(cachedStyle);
```

**Update: If you only want to preserve some style attributes**

You can't choose which attributes you get using `getComputedStyle`, but you can choose which ones you use in $.css. Let's say you only wanted to preserve background-color, width, and left margin (for some reason):

```
var cachedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(domElement);
var propNamesToPreserve = ['backgroundColor','width','marginLeft']; // use the JS-style camelcased attributes, not hyphen-separated CSS properties

var preservedProps = {};
$.each(propNamesToPreserve, function(ix, name) {
    preservedProps[name] = cachedStyle[name];
});

//later
$(domElement).css(preservedProps);
```

Comment: #1. That preserves every attribute. Is there a penalty if all I want is 3 or 4 attributes preserved? #2. By modern browser you mean HTML5?

Comment: It works whether the doctype is HTML4, XHTML, or HTML5. By modern browser I just mean it doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: There's no performance penalty for just 3 or 4 attributes--in fact, it'll probably be faster, since `$.fn.css` iterates through all object properties under the hood. I'll update my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Although your answer is not what I was looking for, I think it's good to know for future reference.